# How prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor (\frac{k}{2})^2 \rfloor =\lfloor \frac{1}{24}n(n+2)(2n-1) \rfloor$

Tags: summation

How prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor (\frac{k}{2})^2 \rfloor =\lfloor \frac{1}{24}n(n+2)(2n-1) \rfloor$? 
 What is $\sum_{k=1}^n \lfloor (\frac{k}{3})^3 \rfloor$?

Comment: For the first one : split the sum in two sums (of even and odd $k$) : the even terms will produce the sum of squares and the odd terms a sum of $\,k^2+k\,$ terms.

Comment: The same applies to the second one. $k$ may be only $3m,3m+1$ or $3m+2$, and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$.